# How do I get my OS (Linux) to automatically turn on F-Lock on my Logitech keyboard?

Tags: logitech-keyboard

I have had a Logitech Internet Navigator keyboard for some years now, and for the most part it works like I want it to.  However, the function keys behave as special keys rather than function keys unless I turn on "F-Lock". Since I prefer to use the functions *as* function keys, that means I always have to remember to press that <kbd>F-lock</kbd> key whenever I boot/wake my system.

Is there any way for Linux to tell the keyboard to turn F-Lock on without me having to press the button?  A simple utility that I can run from the command line would suffice, since I could call it from /etc/pm/hooks and from an init script on system boot.

Answer (score 1):

[KeyTouch](http://keytouch.sourceforge.net/) will allow you to change this. You can swap the function keys around so that when F-Lock is **off**, the function keys will work as desired.

Comment: I couldn't even get the most recent version of keyTouch to compile, and the older versions have very broken init scripts.  Even once I fixed the init scripts by hand, keyTouch didn't work--I could set the F-Keys as function keys, but nothing happens when I press them.

I suspect my kernel is slightly too old to make this work anyway  (CentOS 5.5, kernel 2.6.18).